# CSS full height sidebar, content responsive

Tags: css, design-patterns, layout, responsive-design

I'm trying to create a responsive website layout using skeleton framework but i can't make a full height left sidebar and a top bar.
Show me some ideas about making it with or without skeleton but necessary responsive,here you have an image :
 https://i.stack.imgur.com/wZTCL.png

Example code:

```
<html>
    <body>
    <div id="nav"> This is the navigation menu as shown in the picture below, including the logo</div>
    <div id="topbar"> This is the top search/login bar </div>
    <div id="content">
        <div id="event"> Event card </div>
    </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here is the fiddle of what i have worked on : http://jsfiddle.net/zve96/ .
My question is about how to make the css file to get that result as in the image i posted ?

Comment: Actually, the way that's laid out is very good for mobile-- what I would do is to remove the overflow from the `body` element, and add it to the inner content.

Comment: Yea but i don't know how to figure out this layout.. every time i try to make it in browser i get something totally different..

Comment: Try setting up an example with some code-- that's a good place to start if you want people to help you.

Comment: I updated my question with an html example :)

Comment: Well, I understand what you're trying to do, and I have a working example, but I want to see what you've tried-- not just the elements you have.

Comment: Just set up a jsfiddle with your code.

Comment: The jsfiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/zve96/ .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd do something like this (just solving the sidebar for you). First of all, your CSS and HTML need to match. Your HTML has sidebar as an ID, and your CSS has it as a class.

One issue I'm seeing is that there are explicit widths set on your content-- if you're going to utilize this page layout (and correct me if I'm wrong) your `#content` block should be 100% of your page width apart from the sidebar. If that's the case, then I would add in this CSS:

```
body {
    overflow: hidden;
}
#content {
    width: auto !important;
    height: 100%;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

That takes away the overflow from the entire body and restores it into the #content area, providing for a scrollable area and a simulated `fixed` left sidebar. You can check this out here: http://jsfiddle.net/zve96/1/

Another method would be similar, but utilizing absolute positioning. The CSS would look something like:

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    position: relative;
}
#nav {
    background: #777;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    width: 150px;
}
#topbar {
    background: #333;
    height: 40px;
    left: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
}
#content {
    bottom: 0;
    left: 150px;
    overflow: auto;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 40px;
}
```

And you can check this one out here: http://jsfiddle.net/7Sk7j/

Answer (score 0):

Hopefully this helps, let me know if you need me to tweak it.

CSS:

```
html, body {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 100%;
}
#topbar {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100px;
    background: yellow;
}
#nav {
    float: left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100%;
    background: red;
}
#content {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    margin-left: 200px;
    background: blue;
    padding: 10px;
}
.event-card {
    float: left;
    margin: 10px;
    background: green;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div id="topbar"> </div>
<div id="nav"> </div>
<div id="content">
    <div class="event-card"> </div>
    <div class="event-card"> </div>
    <div class="event-card"> </div>
    <div class="event-card"> </div>
    <div class="event-card"> </div>
</div>
```

Not necessarily "responsive" (use [media queries](http://cssmatter.com/blog/css-media-queries/) for that), but it is fluid width and full height, with event cards that will adjust columns based on width.

DEMO: [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/78CEN/2/)